# Postfix send public dns while send email from aws ec2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, postfix, amazon-web-services

I have a free tier ec2 instance on amazon web services with Ubuntu 14 installed on. WordPress is installed on the instance, along with postix to send emails.

Whenever an email is sent it also sends a full public dns e.g ec2-{publicip}-{region}-aws.amazom.com something like this. And the recipient can view my full public dns assigned by Amazon.

I tried changing my hostname but it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `myhostname` inside postfix' main.cf and restart.

Also check the PTR record of your DNS so your IP does resolve to the name you want to appear, since most mail servers check the reverse records (helo command matches your "real" name)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am unable to find PTR record of my DNS, where should i make that entry. also am i am using cloudflare.com as my NS.

Comment: I'm not sure about AWS, but other hosting allows you yo change the name of your host. Try that way. I found this article in AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/